# How Can I Fetch Monthly DaywiseLatest Login Entry Every Day From Login Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

[image]

I have the above table in which `Date_Time` field I'm using for the showing present/absent mark in my HTML view. The flag field is used for the login/logout status i.e. if `Flag=0` means the user is logged in, the same `Flag=1` user is logged out.
Now I want to get the datewise Present/Absent data on the logged-in the entry of the above table, I got the values but I want the row datewise i.e. as below

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of your code on StackOverflow until there is something that can't be expressed without them.